# Jquery JS To Native JS (Real Tutorial Example)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of JQUERY Script I get from some online example and it is working

But my translated native JS is not working, anyone can help to check where is the mistake and give suggestion?

**jQuery**

```js
function cartAction(action, product_code) {
  var queryString = "";
  if (action != "") {
    switch (action) {
      case "add":
        queryString = 'action=' + action + '&code=' + product_code;
        break;
      case "remove":
        queryString = 'action=' + action + '&code=' + product_code;
        break;
      case "empty":
        queryString = 'action=' + action;
        break;
    }
  }
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "ajax_action.php",
    data: queryString,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#cart-item").html(data);
    },
  });
}
```

I translate it to the native JS like below:

```
function cartAction(action, product_code) {
  var queryString = "";
  if (action != "") {
    switch (action) {
      case "add":
        queryString = 'action=' + action + '&code=' + product_code;
        break;
      case "remove":
        queryString = 'action=' + action + '&code=' + product_code;
        break;
      case "empty":
        queryString = 'action=' + action;
        break;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("cart-item").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("POST", "ajax_action.php?queryString", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: I think this line is problem `"ajax_action.php?queryString"` change it to `"ajax_action.php?" + queryString`